# How to log specific log to text file with logback in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j

I have my current logback file, which to my understanding is a classic logback implementation:

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>Hello %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have a specific log:

```
log.info(String.format("ProxyICA %s has an integrity violation. %s.",
                        processorId.getProxyIca(),
                        fkViolationMsg)
         );
```

that I am trying to get in a text file. The only configuration I need in my logback is to put every instance of this log into a text file. Every other log can default log to the console (which it was doing without the logback.xml).

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of setting it up log to a specific file "Custom-Errors.txt", and to have the logs be deleted if they reach a certain size 20MB or 182 days elapse

```
 <appender name="Custom_Logger 
  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                          
     <file>Custom-Errors.txt</file>
     
     <rollingPolicy 
       class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    
       <fileNamePattern>Custom-Errors-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
       <!-- each file should be at most 20MB, keep 182 days worth of history,but 
         at most 500MB -->
       <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>    
       <maxHistory>182</maxHistory>
       <totalSizeCap>500MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO, DEBUG, TRACE</level>
    </filter>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %date %level [%thread] [%file:%line] %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="CUSTOM_LOGGER" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="Custom_Logger" />
</logger>
```

Then in your java class make a private variable to use the logger like this

```
  private static final Logger CUSTOM_LOGGER = 
                                      LoggerFactory.getLogger("CUSTOM_LOGGER");
```

logging a dependency, or use to log anything you want based on package

```
here is an example of logging a library
  <appender name="ConsoleOutForSpring" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
   </filter>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
     <appender-ref ref="ConsoleOutForSpring" />
</logger>
```

I do admit there are a lot of tags and settings to this logger that are kind of complicated, but reading docs and looking at others examples has helped me.

Here were some docs I noted in my logback.xml

```
<!-- http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html  this helped me with this weird looking stuff i.e. ===>  %date %level [%thread] [%file:%line] %msg%n%throwable   -->

<!-- http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy 
   
     helped me set this up:
                            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                               <fileNamePattern>Errors-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                               <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>    
                               <maxHistory>182</maxHistory>
                               <totalSizeCap>500MB</totalSizeCap>
                            </rollingPolicy>
```

Comment: This works very welll! The only remaining issue I'm having is whenever I use this with the Logback depedency, it isn't maintaing the previous logging standards in the console. I think they were configured with @slf4j lombok attribute. Is there a way to just make the logback.xml file only affect the custom logger, and have everything else stay the same?

Comment: can you get a snippet of the lombok config?

Comment: I believe it is the standard annotation, but here is the configs in the app.properties.

logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.level.com.hrjdj.refarch=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.config=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
logging.level.com.dssc.sc.ddsa=DEBUG

Do these settings need to be converted to logback, or is there a way to have it only use logback for the specific, listed instance?

Comment: I think the best thing to do is make all your logging needs configured in logback, you can log things related to spring also with logback

Comment: Sounds good. How do I replicate these settings to logback.xml? Thank you so much for your help, btw.

Comment: let me update the answer with another example, its nothing too hard just referring to the dependency package

Comment: I should be careful with my suggestions, if you are using this for work, I don't know the full context and don't want to break anything that needs to work a certain way, just use what I have shared safely in your specific context.

Comment: Thank you for the update! The last question I have is regarding the LEVELs. So, would I need to define a console output appender at each level, one for info, one for debug, etc., then assign a bunch of <logger> tags with the proper name= to achieve the same effect?

Comment: right, you would need to specify level in here  <level>INFO</level><--- only INFO
more levels  <level>INFO, DEBUG, TRACE</level>